# Apple Developer Enterprise Program requirement "Your organization must have 100 or more employees."

Tags: ios, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I have this scenario and I strugge to find a solution: There's a company with about 30 employees, this company must distribute an in-house iOS app for their employees' devices (iPad). 
The app must be distribuited through the company website in a restricted area (wireless distribution via an URL).

At first glance, the Apple developer program that best fits this need is the Apple Developer Enterprise Program, that's fine, but if I take a look at the requirements I see this statement "Your organization must have 100 or more employees."

In this case the company has about 30 employees, can it in any case apply for the Apple Developer Enterprise Program?

Is there an alternative way to distribuite an in-house app without the Apple Developer Enterprise Program?

I see that it is possible to use TestFlight or ad-hoc distribution, but they are only intended for testing purposes.

Thanks

Comment: 30 employees? Take your MacBook, plug the iPads one by one, install with Xcode.

Comment: Do I take it that the target device won't connect to the Internet?  If so then enterprise program won't work anyway as the devices need to connect to the Internet every month to validate the enterprise program keys. If you can't use App Store B2B private app then @Cœur has a good solution, but you will need to reinstall every 120 days or so (I can't remember the default ad-hoc provisioning profile validity)

Comment: @Cœur It's not possible for many reason, the company is my client, I can't go to their office anytime I need to update the app and confiscate every iPad to do the job, not in 2020 where you must use CI/CD.

Comment: @Paulw11 the target device can use internet through WiFi and mobile connection. The Cœur solution doesn't fits my needs, I can't build and reinstall the app every 120 days, it's cumbersome.

Comment: The you should definitely investigate a private B2B app distributed via an MDM solution.  This is a standard app store build that never expires and can be installed only on your own devices

Comment: @Paulw11 you mean this: https://www.coletiv.com/blog/distribute-custom-b2b-ios-app/

Comment: Yes.  There is also a good WWDC2019 session on app distribution that covers B2B vs enterprise, when you should use each one and the pros/cons

Comment: Best thing to do would be to simply add device's UDID in provisioning profiles and create a diwai link.why waste 299 dollars . Or use a apple business manager account and using redemsion codes or MDM Solutions also you can distribute the app

Comment: @Help but with diwai link I still have to reinstall the app every 120 days?

Comment: then you can either go with the Apple Business Manager Account & use one of the available  MDM (Mobile Device Management) Solution.

Answer (score 4):

At the end I contacted the Apple developers support,  for my case they said this:

"In this case your client can normally register with the company program and then join the Apple Business Manager, a program that allows the distribution of apps internally through the use of specific codes."